# Spaces and tab comparison string Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, tabs, spaces

I wrote simple test:

```
   func testTabs() {
        let tabbed = "\t"
        let spaced = "    "

        XCTAssert(tabbed == spaced, "Comparison is illegal")
    }

   func testTabs() {
        let tabbed = "\t"
        let tab = "    "

        XCTAssert(tabbed == tab, "Comparison is illegal")
    }
```

if fails for using actual '**tab**' spacing,
it fails for 4 spaces,2 spaces.
So I compare **tab** for **\t** and it fails. ( also fails for any equivalent).

Should it work at all?
Should I never use **tab** in strings if I want do the tests? 
Let me show what I mean:

```
func generateSomeString() -> String {
    let array = ["Some","Stupid","People","Don't","Read","But","Comment"]
    let string = array.joined(separator: "\t")
    return string
}

func testStrings() {
    let string = generateSomeString()
    let expectedString = "Some    Stupid    People    Don't    Read    But    Comment"
    print(string)
    XCTAssert(string == expectedString, "Comparison is illegal")
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect a tab character to be equal to any number of spaces? It's no different from comparing the letter O to the digit 0. In other words, not at all the same.

Comment: @maddy thats right

Answer (score 0):

Tabs and spaces are whitespace, but are not the same thing.

You can replace `\t` to an expected number of spaces, and then test it...

Comment: ye, that workaround will work for sure. But it also means, I never can use \t in my strings if I want to use tests. or I need to replace all spaces(and/or tabs) in constant strings with \t and loose their visuality and readability.